# Como fazer um trigger draggable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, ui-draggable

Estou com dificuldades para posicionar um elemento no centro quando clico num método de zoom, um elemento [UI JQuery Draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable) é arrastado fora para o canto, e clico em uma ferramenta de zoom, ele acaba desaparecendo da tela... porque foi arrastado para o canto da tela...

```
function zoomIn() {
   var scale = 1.0;
        scale=+.1;
    $('.objeto').css({'transform':'scale('+scale+')'});
} 

function  limitPage(ui, vh, vw, content_vh) {
                if ((ui.position.left + (ui.position.left / 4)) > vw) {
                    ui.position.left=-(ui.position.left - 30);
                    return false;
                } else if ((Math.abs(ui.position.left) + (Math.abs(ui.position.left) / 4)) > vw) {
                    ui.position.left=+(ui.position.left + 30);
                    return false;
                } else if ((ui.position.top + (ui.position.top / 4)) > vh) {
                    ui.position.top=-(ui.position.top - 30);
                    return false;
                } else if ((Math.abs(ui.position.top) + (Math.abs(ui.position.top) / 4)) > content_vh) {
                    ui.position.top=+(ui.position.top + 30);
                    return false;
                } 
            }

$('.objeto').draggable({

                        height :'auto',
                        cursor: 'grabbing',
                        // revertDuration: 250,
                        zIndex: 3,
                        start: function (event, ui) {
                        },
                        drag: function (event, ui) {

                              var vw = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth || 0, window.innerWidth || 0);
                var content_vh = (vw * 2) - (vw / 2);
                                  
                var vh = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight || 0, window.innerHeight || 0);
                            return limitPage(ui, vh, vw, content_vh);  
                        },
                        stop: function (event, ui) {
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Bom dia Ivan, não sei se já conseguiu resolver, se conseguir colocar um exemplo testável em alguma plataforma online acho que seria melhor. Aqui reclamou do $('.objeto').css('transform':'scale('+scale+')'); na função de zoom, troquei para 1 parametro apenas $('.objeto').css('transform: scale('+scale+')'); pois para passar dois parametros seria com virgula.

Comment: @Cleverson, falha minha, era pra ser um parâmetro em objeto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi aqui, na verdade eu não precisei pensar no elemento através do evento dragabble, mas no elemento renderizado que utiliza o draggable, cada vez que chamo a ferramenta de zoom, eu reposiciono o elemento passando style para o mesmo:

```
 var vw = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth || 0, window.innerWidth || 0), canvas = document.getElementById('meu_objeto');
  if (isZoom) {
 /* Aqui em baixo estou capturando a largura da tela, 
    removendo a largura do elemento arrastado mais 
    as duas margens totais 150px, que seria 75px de cada lado, 
    dividindo por dois, tenho a distância do elemento que seria
    arrastado reposicionado ao centro
 */
    var size =  (vw - (canvas.width + 150)) / 2; 
     canvas.style.position = 'absolute';
     canvas.style.left = size+'px';
     canvas.style.top = 0;
     canvas.style.zIndex = 'auto';
  }
```

Não foi preciso fazer um trigger, apenas reposicionar o elemento.